# Auto copy on double click in Terminator

Tags: command-line, terminator

I used to be a heavy user of **iTerm2** and one of it's most useful features I found was to auto-copy the text to clipboard when I double click and select something. I recently transitioned to Ubuntu and I'm using **Terminator** as my terminal emulator.

Is there a way I can add this functionality to Terminator or if this already exists somewhere?

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but do you know about Linux's primary selection? If you select something, you can then middle click somewhere else, and it will "paste" from the selection (as opposed to the normal clipboard)?

Comment: Oh I didn't know about it that should actually work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu (and many Linux systems) have a secondary clipboard - the [X selection buffer](http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/xclipboard.html). When you select something, it is automatically added to this buffer. Then you can middle-click where you want to paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the middle click, you may find these helpful:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> => copy

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> => paste

Answer (score 0):

This feature exists in terminator.
Go to preferences. Then go to profiles. In the generals tab there is an option "Copy on Selection". You can check or uncheck that.